# Можно ли привязать несколько Label'ов к одному Outlet'у?

Tags: xcode, swift, view, label

Собственно сам вопрос в заголовке.
Имеется множество лейблов и view'ов. 
Хотел создать один outlet для всех лейблов, что бы у каждого было одинаковое отображение и так же с view'ами, но привязать несколько таких к одному оутлету в коде не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `outlet collection`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И затем настраивайте как хотите:

```
@IBOutlet var labelsCollection: [UILabel]!

...
labelsCollection.forEach { (label) in
    // Все что необходимо, к примеру:
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 40)
}
```

Comment: Превосходно! Спасибо